# How to prevent the parent node from being checked on a hierarchy when it has a single child node?

Tags: jquery, dynatree

As you can see on the image below, when marking the "Guest" all parents that have a single child gets checked too. But I actually want just the "Guest" checked and its parents unchecked as in the "Account's manager"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Accounts Manager" box is in the `indeterminate` state, meaning that all of its children are not all checked or all unchecked. When there is only one child, though, the state can never be `indeterminate` since all of the one children are either checked or not. So what you're asking for doesn't make sense...

I guess you could add another child with `display:none` or something to provoke an `indeterminate` state, but I don't know why you'd want to do that.

Comment: It does makes sense on my context. I'm checking a Guest's role, not its parents. And I want the `indetermined` state to shows the user that he can not check the parents once it has checked a child (if he does check, now all children will be checked, as it inherit the role's children privileges). But I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

[stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("whatever[type='checkbox']").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); don't bubble the check boxes to the parent.
});
```

Comment: Is it for the Dynatree? I did not get it... Have you tested?

Comment: Try $("#tree").dynatree({ selectMode: '1' });

Comment: I want the selectMode 3 so that the checkboxes can turn into `indeterminated` state as in the image for the "Account's manager".